# User Permission in PHP

Tags: php, bash, ssh, permissions

I'm working on an online-platform that allows to write PHP code on a textarea
and see that code on an iframe.

> Why? because i want to release API for another platform so that users
>   can try them without problems

With this platform users can create/edit/delete files.
Every user has a personal folder that contains his own files, the folder's name is equal to the username of the user.
My problem is that I don't want a user to edit files of other users, but only his own.
How can i do this?
If a user writes the code that refers to the folder of another user,

```
//for example 
f_open('../path_to_differt_dir');
```

this user could delete all the files belonging to the other user.
**How can I avoid this?** 
I wish that ONLY the functions written by me can change file, instead the functions created by the user, however, does not have permission to change anyone file. 
That way I could control all this, But I don't know how to do something like this.

Comment: When a user requests a file path (`www.example.com/Script47/file.php`) check if the current `$_SESSION['username']` matches the username part in the URL. This means when they "login" you'd need to set a session for the username.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but that's not my problem. If a user in his own page write a php code like fopen('../path_to_other_user');  the user session is it okay, but he can read/delete or whatever he wants to the file of the other user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you - you are building an "online" PHP compiler.
Well you have bigger concerns than just relative path.

The best way to approach that will be to use a PHP sandbox class that will enable you to avoid unsafe code.

Here is a nice project (the best I know of): [A full-scale PHP 5.3.2+ sandbox class that utilizes PHP-Parser to prevent sandboxed code from running unsafe code.](https://github.com/fieryprophet/php-sandbox)

When doing it like that you can `whitelist` the functions you want and black list others - this way you can leave out `exec, shell_exec ...`

For relative path issues you can always create a virtual host for the userfolder when the folder is created and box him with basedir:

```
<VirtualHost 178.154.120.143:80>
    <Directory /httpdocs/user/userfolder>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "C:/httpdocs/user/userfolder"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem here is that you will need to flush the changes which will normally require a server restart. But there are solutions for that too:

[configure virtualhost without restarting apache web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/92139/how-can-i-configure-virtualhost-without-restarting-apache-web-server)

I Hope it helps.

Comment: **Thanks a lot**, Right now I have two choices, one is that you offer, the other choice is this: [PHPGACL](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/)